# Ways to calculate number by multiplying

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to calculate how many ways there are to calculate the same number by multiplying 3 smaller or same numbers. But with only one permutation of the three given numbers.

For example number 6 can be calculated by

```
1 * 1 * 6 = 6
2 * 3 * 1 = 6
```

but it can also by calculated by the following permutations of `[ 1, 1, 6 ]`, but I want to count it only as a one option

```
1 * 6 * 1 = 6
6 * 1 * 1 = 6
```

I know how to achive this by using s very slow algorithm of 3 embedded `for` cycles, so is there any mathematical trick on how to do this better?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

This is for numbers within `<1; n> of N` where `n` is the givin number.

Pseudocode solution would be apprecieted.

Comment: does $\left[1,-1,-6\right]$ counts?

Comment: No, only positive numbers.

Comment: i can give you some ways to calculate it faster(still using loop) but i dont think there is a way to calculate it without a loop, because if there was a way it was a great way to check if a number is a prime(i am also assuming that you are talking about 3 integers) will it still help you?

Comment: Everything will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing the number
into prime factors,
write
$n
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{v_p(n)}
$
where
$P$ is the set of primes
and
$v_p(n)$
is the exponent for which
$p^v$ exactly divides $n$
(i.e.,
$p^{v_p(n)} \mid n$
and
$p^{v_p(n)+1} \not\mid n$.

If you want to
see how many ways
$n$
can be written as the
product of $m$ factors,
let these factors be
$(n_k)_{k=1}^m$
so that
$n
=\prod_{k=1}^m n_k
$.

Since
$n_k
=\prod_{p \in P} p^{v_p(n_k)}
$,
by unique factorization
we have
$v_p(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^mv_p(n_k)
$.

The problem is now reduced
to finding
the number of ways
each exponent
of each prime that divides $n$
can be written as
the sum of
$m$ non-negative values.

Your turn.

Comment: Could you please post also a pseudocode for this if possible? Because I do not really understand it when written in this way. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to find the number of way to create $x$ you can do the following:

$$x=\begin{cases}[x,1,1]\\ [p,q,1]\\ [a,b,c]\end{cases}$$

for the first case you dont need to work. for the second case you need to do some search:

for which $i\in\Bbb N, i\in [2,\sqrt x]$ you have $x\equiv0\pmod{i}$

all the possible ways to create the number $x$ in the second way will be $\left[i,\frac xi,1\right]$

now the third way will be the trickiest:

first of all you have to note that $[a,b,c]=[a\times b,c,1]$ so you can repeat on the second part but instead of searching for which $i$ you have $x\equiv0\pmod{i}$ you will seach for which $j$ you have $i\equiv0\pmod{j}$ and $\frac xi\equiv0\pmod{j}$

Comment: Could you please post also a pseudocode for this if possible? Because I do not really understand it when written in this way. Thank you very much in advance.